# Database documentation / tips / resources

Tags: database

Hope this question isn't too vague.

I was wondering if there was any documentation or guidance on the database(s) underpinning Craft?

I am going to be working on a website with a fair amount of data and, crucially, the need to pull quite a lot of pieces of data frequently.

You can see a version of it here: http://unlockinglovelocks.co.uk

At the moment, using the dropdowns, you can navigate to a large picture which is mapped, so that clicking on each padlock will bring up its details. Eventually, my friend who requested the site expects to catalog a large number of these (potentially several large images, each featuring dozens of locks, related to just one site --- multiple sites per area --- multiple areas)

Am looking for a setup that won't end up being slow or inefficient. Basically want to understand a bit more about how the data storage with Craft works, so I can try and do it right :p

Any recommended resources would be welcome - I have had a google, and a browse of the Craft docs, without much luck.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not 100% sure of what you're looking for.  Are you looking on advice on how you might architect the database tables in a plugin for that particular site?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure - I read somewhere that Craft just sticks everything in one big table? In which case, should I create a plugin or something to allow me to separate them out into different tables?

Comment: Hi Feathers, this question is far to broad for the Stack Exchange format. I recommend joining the [Craft Slack channel](https://craftcms.com/community#slack) instead... there are tons of friendly people who can help you get a better understanding of Craft's inner workings!

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer this without specifics on what you're looking for and what your plugin is trying to do, but I'd recommend following the [plugin development docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction), which includes [working](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/database) with [databases](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/migrations).

I'd also recommend using somethign like https://pluginfactory.io to generate the plugin boilerplate code for the plugin components you might need.